# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user .NET Core IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, iis, asp.net-core

Published .NET Core project to local IIS but I'm not able to acces my local database.

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll ("Login failed for user xxx")

**Connection string:**

```
"MarketingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MarketingDatabase;user id=xxx;password=xxx;Trusted_Connection=false"
```

User has all necessary permissions to access the database. When I run it from visual studio I can connect to the database.

**Application pool settings:**

identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tried switching to LocalSystem identity without results.

Comment: _User has all necessary permissions to access the database._ You should look again :) It's sure that the suer can't access the database. Sometimes when recreating the database we forget to re-add the rights for the user.

Comment: Can you login to the server using SQL Management Studio and those credentials?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Double checked user has sysadmin role and is db owner of the database.

Comment: @JayV I can login with the user using SQL Management Studio

Comment: go check the database logs with18456 errors in management studio. search dba.stackexchange.com with the Severity and state codes.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 didn't find any Error: 18456 logs

Comment: Test with an account you know won't fail. I.E. *SA* account. If it's still failing you know the issue is not related to permissions, at the server and database level at least. Often, I find the process of elimination to be the most effective approach to troubleshooting.

Comment: Very often happens that you think that EF is connecting to a DB while it is connecting to another DB (you find a lot of issues also on stack overflow). Check also the Default/Debug/Release web configs.